# Plugin add faild from github

Tags: git, cordova, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

I need image resize.

Because I tried to install this plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-image-resizer.git
```

But I got this err.

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/protonet/cordova-plugin-image-resizer.git via registry.

How can i fix this err.

Can u pls help me..

Thanks

Comment: check this issue https://github.com/JoschkaSchulz/cordova-plugin-image-resizer/issues/25

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I forked in github.Bt after i dont know how plugin installed.Can u help me..

Comment: you will need to add a package.json file something like this: https://github.com/dhavalsoni2001/ImagePicker/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Sry.still i dont understand.Already my project have package,json.

Comment: no the plugin needs a package.json.. it is an open bug

Comment: No.the same plugin installed another sys..

Comment: maybe that sys has an older cordova version.. _check the github issue linked_

Comment: How can i install cordova old version..

Comment: `npm remove -g cordova` and `npm install -g cordova@version_number`

Comment: Thanks.I will try..